# F# Getting the size of a type parameter at runtime

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a function:

```
let foo (a : 'T[])
```

I would like to know the size of T

One approach is:

```
  let t = a.[0].GetType() 
  let size = Marshal.SizeOf(t)             
  if size < 4 then //something
  else //something else
```

But this has a few problems. GetType is slow and I have to first check if the array is empty or not. Adding another step and more code. Is it possible to improve on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use typeof:

```
let t = typeof<'T>
let size = Marshal.SizeOf(t)             
if size < 4 then //something
else //something else
```

Comment: Can't `Marshal.SizeOf(t)` be replaced by [`sizeof<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.sizeof%5B't%5D-type-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) ? or they do different things ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht - [sizeof](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L473) invokes the `sizeof` operator directly, and I'm not sure what `Marshal.SizeOf` does since the docs talk about unmanaged types and it's implemented as an external call in the BCL.

Comment: It looks like sizeof<'T> is the thing to do, it appears return the expected values and is fast.

Comment: @jackmott - `sizeof` returns the size of the type at runtime including any padding, so if that's what you need then it would be better.

Comment: Beware that the concept of "size" may not make sense for all types. Primitive ones are OK, but you better not rely on it for more complex stuff.